# How to align a th in bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

so
Ive some issues with a bootstrap's table.
TH dont align, and i dont know what to do.

the result is like this table:

[image: Bootstrap]

my CSS is a simple

```
#tabela{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Try adding !important; maybe bootstrap has a style declared for <th> that overrides your css.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are using bootstrap give a class of text-center in th:

```
<th class="text-center">Content</th>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the property text-align on the TH element directly to overwrite bootstraps styling.

```
#tabela tr th,
#tabela tr td {
    text-align: center;
}
```